# How can IIS 7.5 have the error pages for a site reset to the default configuration?

Tags: iis7, error, 403-forbidden, http-code-500, http-code-503

A mishap occurred with web.config to accommodate a subsite existing.  I made use of `“<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">”`.  Essentially it was a workaround put in place for nested web.config files which was causing a conflict.  The result was that error pages were not being handled properly.  Error 500 was being passed to the client for every type of error encountered.

Removal of the offending inheritInChildApplications tag from the root web.config restored normal operations of most of the error handling, but for some reason error 503 is a correct response header, but the IIS server is performing the custom actions for error 403.4 which is a redirect to https.

I'm looking to restore defaults for error pages so that the behavior once again is restored.  I then can re-add customizations for the error pages.

Comment: I wanted to add that the response header from the web server is indeed error 503, as seen by Webscarab but I'm being redirected to HTTPS and not correctly just presenting an error like before.  Could it be that this is a default rule being triggered to use.

Comment: Before modification to the web.config file the error pages behaviour was correct.  After the modification and restoration back of web.config the incorrect behaviour was experienced.

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to reset a lot of my site's values using appcmd, but I had to dig into specific configurations I wanted to change, which I'll describe a bit below. I know for sure that this works with IIS 7, but I'm not 100% certain whether it passed on to 7.5 so YMMV.

appcmd isn't in my cmd path on any of my installations (though these machines are 2k8sp2) - anyway, from cmd prompt as administrator type:

> cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv

then to get a nice set of examples type:

> appcmd reset config /?

and to see which settings you want to reset, type:

> appcmd reset config /section:?

The /section:? will give you a big dump, so I dumped it to a text file for my personal needs.  You'll end up with up everything in the configs in the namespace system.web, system.webServer, system.net and a handful of others.

The command I ended up using (I needed to reset my httpErrors) is below:

> appcmd reset config /section:httpErrors

I hope that's helpful! More info on appcmd here:
[at the Microsoft TechNet site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Appcmd looks promising to do what I'm intending to do.  In the recent past I've leveraged it from Powershell to view current requests.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nested directories can have their own *web.config* file, but like CSS files the rules you set cascade down.

For sub directories with their own *web.config* settings, Best practice is to:

1. Override rules you set in root *web.config* file by setting them as off or to the value you need.
2. Use applications (similar to virtual directories) instead of actual directories. The applications will not inherit parent rules.

Comment: That is what I read when I set it up, but the behaviour I'm getting is not correct.  Is it possible my web.config file is corrupt or does IIS need to be reset?

Comment: Anytime you make changes to web.config the site automatically restarts.  As for IIS Reset, the command is the same as simply rebooting IIS, or the whole server to make sure.  One thing that usually cases errors is the ordering of IIS modules.  Is your code calling any specific ones such as ARR

Comment: I'll see what the order of modules you mentioned next week.  The code is setting the response header, but IIS appears to not be taking the correct action for that particular response header.  I probably should be using 403 response, but still I'm puzzled about the 403.4 behaviour presentation.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  403 is an unauthorized header.  I am guessing you are somehow trying to restrict access to certain directories?  If you give us an overall picture of what you are trying to do maybe we can diagnose it.   

One extra now.  I have found that child "applications" those that you actually run as applications versus virtual directories need to have their own /bin/ app-code etc folders.   That does not cascade up to the parent application.

Comment: What I'm using the current 503 response for is with a limiter for unpleasant bot behaviour to mitigate bandwidth consumption and server resources.  If a visitor from an IP address requests more than 3 http requests per second they are flagged and blocked for the remainder of that second and then the restriction is released and the process is repeated.  Organic traffic isn't affected unless crazy fast clicking from the user is performed.  Normally the 503 response is sent to the browser flowed with a message, but now its an https redirect and that is a flaw.

Comment: You should look into Dynamic Ip Restrictions for IIS.  It does this automagically.   We do this server side with most of the code we write.  Just because we like to log everything to MySQL.  But dynamic Ip restrictions will give them the "slow down" message you are looking for.  

As for bots, a good robots.txt will handle the good bots.  The crappy bots, we usually block them as best we can by popping their Ip addresses into windows firewall rules.

Comment: I'll look into that!  Thanks for an alternative approach.  However, I'm still concerned about correcting the puzzling behaviour of IIS not providing desired actions for error 503.

Comment: It can be so many things, from custom errors, to the ordering of modules to an app pool crapping out.  To really figure out what is going on it might be worth tracing and logging everything.  

From my experience though, if your goal is simply to block bots, there is a cleaner and simpler approach that I suggested.  IIS is not as flexible as apache when it comes to configs.  

One thing you can consider is to place IIS behind NginX and have it act a reverse proxy.  Your NGINX sever can host a firewall to accomplish your bot blocking efforts.

Comment: I wasn't aware of NGINX.  Again, thanks for bringing something new to my attention.  It is my policy to correct something that is not correctly operating before adopting something new or trying to bandaid the problem with an alternative option.  I'll see what I can find in logs.  I don't believe it is app pool crashing.  We have debugDiag installed and will produce a crash dump if that occurs, which it hasn't.  Event viewer doesn't report any app pool unusual behaviour either.  All I have that I can think of is IIS logs that I haven't viewed.

Comment: I appreciate all the new material you have brought to my attention and have probably very little you don't know about to yours.  If you haven't seen this dynamic bot blocking application I suggest you take a look.  http://crawlwall.com/  It is in Beta and the developer seems very passionate about its development.  I don't like the PHP dependency at the moment, but maybe it will evolve beyond that.  Time will tell.

Comment: If you can use crawlwall with an apache reverse proxy in front of an IIS server, then you are set.  PHP runs really well on IIS7 / 7.5 and 8.  But since its using htaccess and robots.txt re-writing, might be better just to use apache in front of iis.